# Calculating factorial multiple times in a loop only works the first time through

Tags: c

This program that calculates the value of `n!` only gives the correct value the first time through the loop.  On each subsequent time through the loop it gives an incorrect value.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,result=1;
    while(1){
        do{
            printf("\nInput n:");
            scanf("%d",&n);
        }while(n<1);
        for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            result*=i;
        }
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            printf("%d",j);
            if(j!=n)
            {
                printf("x");
            }
        }
        printf("=%d",result);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong when it makes a mistake?

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're not getting the same value for `result` each time through the outer loop is because you don't reset its value when you start the loop.

The first time through the loop `result` starts with a value of 1.  The next time through, it starts with the value it had when it finished the last iteration through the loop because you didn't bother to change it.

You want to set `result` to 1 at the start of the loop.

```
while(1){
    result = 1;
    do{
        ...
```

Comment: @CatDragon Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.